# How do I run some code only once in Dart?

Tags: dart

I wonder if there's a language sugar/SDK utility function in Dart that allows to protect a certain code from running more than once?
E.g.

```
void onUserLogin() {
    ...
    runOnce(() {
        handleInitialMessage();
    });
    ...
}
```

I know I can add a global or class static boolean flag to check but it would be accessible in other functions of the same scope with a risk of accidental mixup in the future.

In C++ I could e.g. use a local static bool for this.

Comment: You can use private static bool flag in dart as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality to prevent code from running more than once. You need some kind of external state to know whether it actually did run.

You can't just remember whether the function itself has been seen before, because you use a function expression ("lambda") here, and every evaluation of that creates a new function object which is not even equal to other function objects created by the same expression.

So, you need something to represent the *location* of the call.

I guess you could hack up something using stack traces. I will not recommend that (very expensive for very little advantage).

So, I'd recommend something like:

```dart
class RunOnce {
  bool _hasRun = false;
  void call(void Function() function) {
    if (_hasRun) return;
    // Set after calling if you don't want a throw to count as a run.
    _hasRun = true;
    function();
  }
}

...
  static final _runOnce = RunOnce();
  void onUserLogin() {
    _runOnce(handleInitialMessage);
  }
```

It's still just a static global that can be accidentally reused.